# My React Native app is stuck in loading loop

Tags: android, ios, react-native, metro-bundler

When running the react-native run-ios and opening the simulator, the app just keeps reloading. In the Metro bundler I get "warn Error: not opened" over and over again.

Sometimes the app stabilizes again and I can keep developing, but then if I reload again it just loops around again maybe 20-30 times.

Sometimes it gets stuck on "Downloading Javascript bundle" loading screen at 100% and then when I reload it is the same story.

Sometimes the app crashes...

I have tried going back to the previous state where it didn't reload constantly but to no avail.

This seems to happen when using Live Reload only. But I'd rather have live reload than manually reloading.

Does anyone know why this happens, and have a solution?

Comment: Is your IDE automatically saving changes?

Comment: Nope, manual saving

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer from a different question about Refreshing on expo. If you are getting the constant 'Refreshing...' pop-up and you're using Mac, it's because iCloud is constantly accessing the folder. Change the folder name to 'tmp' to mitigate this. I've had the Refreshing... error many times for months now but this fixed it. Hope you found a solution OP.